# ssh into kubernetes pod from outside the cluster without OpenSSH running in the pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssh, terminal, kubectl

I want to ssh into the pod from outside the cluster. I connect to the pod that runs OpenSSH via a bastion server inside the cluster and connect to the bastion from outside the cluster. But as I said the pod has to run open ssh.
How can I ssh into pods that do not run OpenSSH?
I suppose you can proxy or pipe the `kubectl exec -it` to a bastion server but I do not know how to do it.
It is a very important project and I greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Why is ssh specifically an important thing to do?  What does the pod do otherwise?  Usually you don't get interactive shells in Kubernetes pods at all, or if you do it's only for emergency debugging, and not from somewhere you couldn't otherwise run `kubectl`.

Comment: Kind of like Google cloud shell

Comment: Google uses a temporary VM to do it but basically the same functionality but in kubernetes

Comment: Especially if the pods aren't running ssh daemons, you'll have to build this yourself.  You can use Kubernetes RBAC to give an ssh relay pod permission to do `kubectl exec` but nothing else.

Comment: I run `openssh` servers in `docker` inside Kubernetes [exposing the TCP ports](https://blog.lazybit.ch/expose-tcp-and-udp-services-using-ingress-nginx/) and use [`authorized_keys`](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/openssh) config to disable TTY allocation, are just for proxying connections. If you don't have an `openssh` server to connect too then maybe consider implementing one using [`paramiko`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/server.html) but never heard of using `ssh` with no server to handle the connections at the other end.

Comment: I am using paramiko as the ssh server (bastion) inside  the cluster to connect to relay ssh connection from outside the cluster to containers running openssh.
`kubectl exec -it bash`  kind of acts as ssh server at the end. How can can I connect it to ssh relay?

Comment: How can I ssh into pods that do not run OpenSSH? AFAIK you can't. As a workaround I would suggest to take a look at [telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/reference/connecting.html).